# basic python, reading a global input for all inputs?

Tags: python, input

I have a sort of text adventure game with multiple inputs here:

```
import time
def menu():
print("This is the menu")
if input == 9:
    menu()
print("Hello! Welcome to the world!")
heroname = str(input("What is your name?"))
heroname = heroname.lower()
print("Ah", heroname, "What an interesting name!!!")
sex = int(input("Now..are you a boy or a girl?(1 for boy, 2 for girl)"))
if sex == 1:
  print("A male you are!")
  herosex = 'sir'
if sex == 2:
  print("Why greetings m'lady!")
  herosex = 'mlady'
print("Please wait as we travel.")
time.sleep(1)
print(".")
time.sleep(1)
print(".")
print(herosex, ", we arrive!")
print("I wish to introduce you to the menu!")
print("1 - Okay!")
print("2 - I refuse!")
whatismenu = int(input("Enter your choice"))
if whatismenu == 1:
  print("Ah, the menu is a dialogue that can be opened using 9 at any time beyond this point")
print("Here, try it!")

if whatismenu == 2:
print("You are quite rude, lets try this again. I would like to introduce you to the menu!")
print("1 - Very well, I am not trying to be a douchebag I just randomly become a dogboy")    
whatismenu2 = int(input("Enter your choice"))
if whatismenu2 == 1:
    print("Ah, the menu is a dialogue that can be opened using 9 at any time beyond this point")
```

The problem i'm having is where i'm trying to create a way to open the defined menu at line 4:

```
if input == 9:
```

Basically through all these different variable inputs, if the user ever presses 9 when answering them, it should open the menu function but I have no idea how to do this without testing if answer is == 9 for every input variable. If anyone has any advice on how to fix this and any advice on how I can make the direction of this code more clean for a text adventure game, it would be greatly appreciated, i am really new to python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making your own input function lets just say call it myInput()

Replace all your input()'s with myInput()'s so that myInput automatically checks if they entered a 9.

```
def myInput(prompt = ""):
    inp = "9"
    while inp == "9":
        # Ask the user the same question until they enter something other than 9
        inp = input(prompt)
        if inp == "9":
            menu()

    return inp
```

My python is rusty so you might have to change something here